# Unable to get 3D view of rectangle in OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glm-math

I am following this tutorial. 
https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems - subtopic going 3D section i am not able to get the output only blank screen.

Here is my code:

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "shaders.h"
#include "camera.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

GLFWwindow* window;
GLuint VBO, VAO,EBO;
unsigned int texture;
const unsigned int screenwidth = 800;
const unsigned int screenheight = 600;
float vertices[] =
{
    0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  
};
unsigned int indices[] = 
{
    0, 1, 3,
    1, 2, 3  
};
void glfwinitializer()
{
    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(screenwidth, screenheight, "Question 2 : Camera Space", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
void initializeVertex()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
void initializeTexture()
{
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("text.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

}
int main()
{
    glfwinitializer();
    Shader ourShader("vertexshader.vs", "fragmentshader.fs");
    initializeVertex();
    initializeTexture();
    glm::mat4 projection(1);
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)screenwidth / (float)screenheight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    ourShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f); 
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        ourShader.use();
        glm::mat4 model(1);
        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(-55.f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        ourShader.setMat4("model", model);
        glm::mat4 view(1);
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
        ourShader.setMat4("view", view);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

My vertex shader is :

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection*view*model*vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x,aTexCoord.y);
}
```

Trying to implement this code. I am getting blank output.
[Output Image Here : No Rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucYdr.jpg)
If I comment the three mode, view and projection matrix and remove from vertex shader file. . I am able to see the rectangle on the screen.
[Output Image Here: Rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZRzP.jpg)

I have one more question

```
glm::mat4 model(1);
glm::mat4 view(1);
glm::mat4 projection(1);
```

contains only value 1. When I am trying to comment following lines

```
//model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(-55.f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
//view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
//projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)screenwidth / (float)screenheight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

and run the program without changing

```
gl_position = projection*view*model*vec4(aPos, 1.0);
```

I am getting blank screen

Comment: I clicked a little bit through [glm docs](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html) but wasn't able to find the resp. explanation. So, this is a guess (although I'm quite sure). `glm::mat4 model(1);` makes `model` an identity matrix. Multiplying vectors or matrices with an identity matrix does not change them. In general, making `model`, `view`, and `projection` an identity matrix means that model space and clip space get identitcal. (Clip space is the last "3d space" before values are converted two screen coordinates.)

Comment: You said if you don't multiply the position by the matrices you see the rectangle on the screen. If the matrices are all identity matrices (the default constructor or argument of 1.0) then multiplying with them should be exactly the same as not multiplying anything. If by multiplying by the matrices in the shader you don't see the rectangle anymore I think that you're not uploading one of the matrices to the uniforms properly. Incidentally, that's a part of the code you left out.

Comment: @Zebrafish This happens probably in `ourShader.setMat4()` which is not exposed. (or in short: I agree.)

Comment: This is my setMat4() function  :  void setMat4(const std::string &name, const glm::mat4 &mat) const
  {
   glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
  }

Comment: glm::mat4 model(1); Yes, this one is for setting identity matrix and i am able to get rectangle now with gl_position = projection * view * model*vec4(aPos, 1.0); I have forgot ourShader.use();  before calling setMat4 matrix.

Comment: I am getting a rotated rectangle after setting model matrix. But when i am trying to set view and projection. The output screen is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glUniformMatrix4fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) specify the value of a uniform variable for the current program object.

This means [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml) has to be done **before**
 [`glUniformMatrix4fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml).

But you call

```
ourShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
```

before

```
ourShader.use();
```

so the uniform variable `mat4 projection;` is never set.

Change youre code somehow like this:

```
ourShader.use();
ourShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
```

I general your code is fine, except that you should use a minifying function for mipmaps:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have made the changes but there is still blank screen. but I am able to get rectangle with gl_position = projection*model*view*vec4(aPos,1.0); So the identity matrices are being set properly. I uncommented  these lines one by one //model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(-55.f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
//view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
//projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)screenwidth / (float)screenheight, 0.1f, 100.0f); and able to get rotated traingle so my model matrix is working fine

Comment: @DeepanshPandey Yo have to use the `vìew` matrix and the `projection` matrix together. Note, the Z-coordinate of the object has to be between the near and the far plane. In your case near is 0.5 and far is 100.0. The Z-coordinate is -(-3.0). Without `projection` near woluld be -1.0 and far 1.0. Without `view` the Z-cooridnate of the object would be 0.0.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks a lot. My first question in Stackoverflow and it is an awesome experience. I am not able to solve this for last 2 days. Really Thanks a lot.